# how to call or import python class file

Tags: python, python-3.x

HOW CAN I CALL CLASS IN ANOTHER CLASS WITHOUT CIRCULAR IMPORT
i have 2 class file 
the first one is the main and second is the work things inside it

what i wanna  how to call the first in the second and the second in the first

when i do like this

```
from class1_first import class_head

from class1_second import class_work
```

it said 
(most likely due to a circular import)

what should i do to call a memmber in the first class to the second
and the opposite

Comment: If the classes depend on each other so strongly, why are they not in the same file/module?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Maybe the OP wants to do it this way?

Comment: If you could give more detail, that'd be great. Is class1_first a .py file with a class within it called class1_first, which then has a function called class_head? And same for class1_second and class_work?

The you might need from class1_first.class1_first import class_head and the same for the other class.

Or are you trying to do relative imports? Are you trying to instantiate objects of those classes?

Comment: Do the classes themselves depend on each other or only the instances? For example, does ``class_work`` inherit from ``class_head`` or vice versa? Do instances of ``class_work`` produce instance of ``class_head`` and vice versa